# SQLite Placeholder error in Python script

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, discord.py

I am currently working on a discord bot that implements some kind of economy into the server.

While implementing a function to add items to the SQLite Database I ran into this problem:

```
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO items (?,?,?,?,?,?)", item)
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "?": syntax error
```

I already switched to "?" as placeholder thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30257826/sqlite3-operationalerror-near-syntax-error-python) post and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7447938/sqlite3-operationalerror-near-syntax-error-in-python-using-in-operato) post but it didn't help me much.

All values are gotten via arguments to the command in discord and are cast to either string or int.
I use SQLiteStudio and have the datatypes set to "Text" and "Integer" respectively.

```
conn = create_connection(db_file)
        with conn:
            cur = conn.cursor()
            item = (itemname, price, info_text, buy_text, use_text, role,)
            market = (itemname, stock,)
            cur.execute("INSERT INTO items (?,?,?,?,?,?)", item)
            cur.execute("INSERT INTO market (?,?)", market)
```

Comment: The INSERT statement is `INSERT INTO table (col1, col2, ...) VALUES (val1, val2, ...), ...`.  The column list is optional if you're inserting values for every column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your SQL queries are invalid. Syntax for INSERT is one of

```
INSERT INTO table VALUES (...)
INSERT INTO table (columns) VALUES (...)
```

So you should be able to change your query to

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO items VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)", item)
```

and that will fix it. ([docs](https://sqlite.org/lang_insert.html))